# python regex matching "ab" or "ba" words

Tags: python, regex

I tried matching words including the letter "ab" or "ba" e.g. "ab"olition, f"ab"rics, pro"ba"ble. I came up with the following regular expression:

```
r"[Aa](?=[Bb])[Bb]|[Bb](?=[Aa])[Aa]"
```

But it includes words that start or end with ", (, ), / ....non-alphanumeric characters. How can I erase it? I just want to match words list.

```
import sys
import re

word=[]

dict={}

f = open('C:/Python27/brown_half.txt', 'rU')
w = open('C:/Python27/brown_halfout.txt', 'w')

data = f.read()
word = data.split() # word is list

f.close()

for num2 in word:
    match2 = re.findall("\w*(ab|ba)\w*", num2)
    if match2:
        dict[num2] = (dict[num2] + 1) if num2 in dict.keys() else 1

for key2 in sorted(dict.iterkeys()):print "%s: %s" % (key2, dict[key2])
print len(dict.keys())
```

Here, I don't know how to mix it up with "re.compile~~" method that 1st comment said...

Comment: Teachers should stop saying that regular expressions are a solution to every problem known to mankind...

Comment: @KemyLand: This should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

To match all the words with ab or ba (case insensitive):

```
import re

text = 'fabh, obar! (Abtt) yybA, kk'
pattern = re.compile(r"(\w*(ab|ba)\w*)", re.IGNORECASE)

# to print all the matches
for match in pattern.finditer(text):
  print match.group(0)

# to print the first match
print pattern.search(text).group(0)
```

https://regex101.com/r/uH3xM9/1

Comment: Is this case insensitive or **sensitive** ?...It will not match 'Ablotion' !...To make it case-insensitive, add `re.IGNORECASE` flag.

Comment: I tried your one, but it still matches like these. . still includes punctuation and special characters. e.x. "abandoned: 1
"indispensable: 1
"probably: 1
"unable: 1
(halfback: 1
2-baser,: 1banker.: 1
bankers: 2
bankers,: 1
bankers.:

Comment: is there any way to print group 1, in re.search method?

Comment: re.search will return only the first result. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the best tool for the job in this case. They'll complicate stuff way too much for such simple circumstances. You can instead use Python's builtin `in` operator (works for both Python 2 and 3)...

```
sentence = "There are no probable situations whereby that may happen, or so it seems since the Abolition."
words = [''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), token)) for token in sentence.split()]

for word in words:
    word = word.lower()
    if 'ab' in word or 'ba' in word:
        print('Word "{}" matches pattern!'.format(word))
```

As you can see, `'ab' in word` evaluates to `True` if the string `'ab'` is found as-is (that is, exactly) in `word`, or `False` otherwise. For example `'ba' in 'probable' == True` and `'ab' in 'Abolition' == False`. The second line takes take of dividing the sentence in words and taking out any punctuation character. `word = word.lower()` makes `word` lowercase before the comparisons, so that for `word = 'Abolition'`, `'ab' in word == True`.

Comment: Your `words` is a list of chars, probably you wanted in your Comprehension list `sentence.split()` instead?

Comment: @IronFist: I tested the code before posting, but forgot that while writing the answer. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. Strip your string from unwanted chars using the below two
   techniques, your choice:

   a - By building a translation dictionary and using `translate` method:

   ```
   >>> import string
   >>> del_punc = dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in string.punctuation)
   s = 'abolition, fabrics, probable, test, case, bank;, halfback 1(ablution).'
   >>> s = s.translate(del_punc)
   >>> print(s)
   'abolition fabrics probable test case bank halfback 1ablution'
   ```

   b - using `re.sub` method:

   ```
   >>> import string
   >>> import re
   >>> s = 'abolition, fabrics, probable, test, case, bank;, halfback 1(ablution).'
   >>> s = re.sub(r'[%s]'%string.punctuation, '', s)
   >>> print(s)
   'abolition fabrics probable test case bank halfback 1ablution'
   ```
2. Next will be finding your words containing 'ab' or 'ba':

   a - Splitting over whitespaces and finding occurrences of your desired strings, which is the one I recommend to you:

   ```
   >>> [x for x in s.split() if 'ab' in x.lower() or 'ba' in x.lower()]
   ['abolition', 'fabrics', 'probable', 'bank', 'halfback', '1ablution']
   ```

   b -Using `re.finditer` method:

   ```
   >>> pat
   re.compile('\\b.*?(ab|ba).*?\\b', re.IGNORECASE)
   >>> for m in pat.finditer(s):
           print(m.group())


   abolition
   fabrics
   probable
   test case bank
   halfback
   1ablution
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "your string here"
lowercase = string.lower()
if 'ab' in lowercase or 'ba' in lowercase:
    print(true)
else:
    print(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
[(),/]*([a-z]|(ba|ab))+[(),/]*
```